# Python: duplicating each element in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

What's the most pythonic way to do the following? It can either modify the old list or create a new list.

```
oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

newList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> newList = [x for x in oldList for _ in range(2)]
>>> newList
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Above list comprehension is similar to following nested for loop.

```
newList = []
for x in oldList:
    for _ in range(2):
        newList.append(x)
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Pardon my ignorance, but what exactly does the underscore mean?

Comment: That's only to say that you're not going to use the value yielded by `for`.

Comment: @jmu303,  aIKid explained it.

Comment: @jmu303, to clarify, the underscore is a identifier like any other. But by common convention it denotes a throwaway value.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Can you walk me through how python processes the statement?

Comment: @jmu303, See the updated answer. Also see [List comprehensions from tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @jmu303 Imagine writing `dummy_variable` instead of `_`.  It's an easy way to say "the value in this variable doesn't matter, it will never be used"

Answer (score 4):

If you're really into functional programming:

```
from itertools import chain,izip
newList = list(chain(*izip(oldList,oldList)))
```

@falsetru's answer is more readable, so that likely meets the "most pythonic" litmus test.

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: x.extend([y]*2) or x, oldList, [])`

Comment: @gnibbler nice. remind me not to go up against you in a functional programming duel to the death.

Comment: `from itertools import repeat, chain;from functools import partial; list(chain.from_iterable(map(partial(repeat, times=2), oldList)))` :)

Comment: `from itertools import cycle, islice, chain;list(islice(cycle(chain(oldList,[0],oldList)),None,40,5))`

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has done an answer that modifies oldList in place. Here's a fun way

```
>>> oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> oldList += oldList
>>> oldList[::2] = oldList[1::2] = oldList[-4:]
>>> oldList
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two more approaches using functional concepts:

```
>>> list_ = [1,2,3,4]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[[x,x] for x in list_]))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [[x,x] for x in list_])
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

And one using numpy:

```
list(np.array([[x,x] for x in list_]).flatten())
```

And one last as list comprehension:

```
[x for y in zip(list_, list_) for x in y]
```

Comment: Careful using reduce. Your lambda function has O(n^2) complexity. See my comment on roippi's answer which uses `.extend` to keep O(n) complexity

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> (4*(oldList+[0]+oldList))[::5]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Strangely enough

```
$ python -m timeit -s  "oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4]" "[x for x in oldList for _ in range(2)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s  "oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4]" "(4*(oldList+[0]+oldList))[::5]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.995 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
print a*2
```

This will print
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

This can be used if you want duplicate of elements

if you want the duplicate to be next to the original the below code can be used

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    b.append(a[i])
    b.append(a[i])
print b
```

this will print 
b=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]